# ccTouchEnded won't recognize unless long button hold before

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch, kobold2d

I currently have a scene with a layer added to it, and that layer has two ccItemScroller, a layer listing scroller from: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/34353

I appear to be having an issue no one else there is having however.

The problem is that ccTouchEnded will not be called at all unless I hold down a touch for at least 2-3 seconds before releasing. I haven't changed any of their source code.

I understand I haven't posted any code but seeing as no one else is having this issue and I haven't changed their source I guess this is more of a generic question - I simply don't know what to post. If anyone has any suggestions to help me answer I will oblige :)

Has anyone run into this kind of situation before or know a place I can look?

My project is running in Kobold2d, I actually tried to edit the class once to use Kobold2D's method instead but it's the same thing, finger lifts are not detected.

Comment: Are you perhaps using gesture recognizers? They influence regular touch events.

Comment: I did have one on for some reason, but I disabled and there doesn't seem to be a difference. I did notice that, for some reason, if I two finger tap the screen then the ccTouchEnded registers fine and things can easily be selected. This obviously isn't ideal - so strange.

Comment: LearnCocos2D - you've saved me again. Thanks so much. I've read most of your book, going to buy some for Xmas gifts too I think ;) - your involvement in community assistance like this is so breathtaking - cheers. If only I could figure out to show that you answered the question... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Per LearnCocos2D's advice, get your KKInput:
`KKInput* input = [KKInput sharedInput];`

Then disable whatever input is interfering, options being:

`input.gestureTapEnabled = NO;`

`input.gestureDoubleTapEnabled = NO;`

`input.gestureLongPressEnabled = NO;`

`input.gestureSwipeEnabled = NO;`

`input.gesturePanEnabled = NO;`

`input.gestureRotationEnabled = NO;`

`input.gesturePinchEnabled = NO;`

For more info: http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKDOC/KKInput+Gestures